# Umbraco publishing error multiple roots found

Tags: umbraco

I've got a umbraco site and I'm getting a multiple roots found error on publish.

It's a version 4.11.9 site.

What could be causing this?

Comment: In umbracoSettings.config file check `<useDomainPrefixes>false</useDomainPrefixes>` is it `true`? then make it `false`